Query is fast in the proper DB, slow in master
I have a SQL Server 2019 test instance running on VMware that hosts a copy of our production Dynamics CRM database. The reporting team wants to query the database, so we have an AD service account set up within CRM as a read-only user which allows it access to the filtered views within the database.
My issue is that when we include Use CRM_MSCRM, a test query runs fast. If we leave the session in the default master database, the query runs slow even though it is using the fully qualified database.owner.tablename format.
This is what I see:
set statistics time on

use crm_mscrm
go
SELECT top 3 * FROM CRM_MSCRM.dbo.Filtereda360_externalidentifiers; 
go

-- Results:
--a360_clientpayeetypeitems  a360_clientpayeetypeitemsname ...
--NULL                       NULL                          ...
--NULL                       NULL                          ...
--NULL                       NULL                          ...

--(3 rows affected)

 --SQL Server Execution Times:
 --  CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 19 ms.

use master
go
SELECT top 3 * FROM CRM_MSCRM.dbo.Filtereda360_externalidentifiers; 
go

-- Results:
--a360_clientpayeetypeitems  a360_clientpayeetypeitemsname ...
--NULL                       NULL                          ...
--NULL                       NULL                          ...
--NULL                       NULL                          ...

--(3 rows affected)

-- SQL Server Execution Times:
--   CPU time = 130359 ms,  elapsed time = 135731 ms.

I've run it multiple times and the slow one varies by a few seconds but is always over two minutes.  I ran a profiler trace and the first query run from withing the CRM_MSCRM database generates 889 reads, the second run from master does 21,117,645 reads.
I've never seen anything like this. Does anyone have any explanation for why changing the database makes the query using the fully database.owner.tablename have such radically different run times?
The execution plan for the FAST execution.
The execution plan for the SLOW execution.
The master database is set to compatibility level 150 (SQL Server 2019), which makes sense since this is a SQL Server 2019 instance. The CRM database is set to 140 (SQL Server 2017).
In answer to the question in the comments the output of the query below is 1.
SELECT value 
FROM sys.database_scoped_configurations 
WHERE name = 'LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'


The context database determines important optimizer behaviours, depending on the setting of compatibility level and database scoped options like which cardinality estimation model is used.
It doesn't matter that you use three-part names, the settings come from the database the statement is executed from.
Your environment has different compatibility levels for master and the CRM_MSCRM user database. In addition, the database scoped option to use the (generally superior) 'legacy' cardinality estimation model is set for the user database, but not for master.
As a result, you get different plans with different performance characteristics.

In this case the Legacy Cardinality Estimation (found under database > Properties > Options) was set to ON for the CRM database but OFF for the master database.
The options to get consistent performance are:

Change the master database to have Legacy Cardinality Estimation = ON
Change the incoming SQL code to include "USE CRM"
Change the SQL login to default to the CRM database.

